Тексты каких русских писателей можно взять за образец грамотности?
Какие русские писатели писали без ошибок?

Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Unfortunately, this question as it stands now is too broad and not suitable for the format of the site. Please focus on specific, objectively answerable questions. Thank you!
